# Average array of arrays MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection in MongoDB

```
{
   {"values" : [1,2,3,4,5,6]},
   {"values" : [7,8,9,10,11,12]},
   {"values" : [13,14,15,16,17,18]}
}
```

How I can aggregate and take a array with average by indexes?

Like this:

```
{ "average" : [7,8,9,9.66,10.66,12] }
```

**Note**: average[0] = (1 + 7 + 13) / 3

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Aggregation Framework and **$avg**.

$avg can be used in $project or $group.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

> With a single expression as its operand, if the expression resolves to
>   an array, $avg traverses into the array to operate on the numerical
>   elements of the array to return a single value. With a list of
>   expressions as its operand, if any of the expressions resolves to an
>   array, $avg does not traverse into the array but instead treats the
>   array as a non-numerical value.

UPDATE #2:
since the problem is now more clear, i will update my answer.

```
db.stackoverflow027.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "message.testnr":"1111"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$message.content.deflection",
    includeArrayIndex: "position"    
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$position",
    averageForIndex: {$avg: "$message.content.deflection"}/*,
    debug_totalIndexInvolvedInTheAverage: {$sum: 1},
    debug_valueInvolvedInTheAverage: {$push: "$message.content.deflection"},
    debug_documentInvolvedInTheAverage: {$push: "$$ROOT"}*/
  }
},
{
  $sort: {_id:1}
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    average: {$push: "$averageForIndex"}
  }
}
], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

That will give you this output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "average" : [
        6.0, 
        7.0, 
        8.0, 
        9.0, 
        10.0
    ]
}
```

I also added [{ allowDiskUse: true }](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) in order to avoid memory limitations (check the link to have more informations).
Hope now your problem is solved.

You can see some "debug_" property in order to give you the opportunity to figure out what really happen at $group iteration. But you can remove this property in product environmental.

Comment: Thanks!

I know about aggregation and $avg but is not direct way to calculate the average. For example, average between 1, 7 and 13.....2, 8 and 14. Finally the result is a array with averages

Do you understand my problem?

Comment: if is possibile to write a js function to resolve your issue, then you can use MapReduce and load your function directly into the script. Maybe you should also consider to update the original question. LINK: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/

Comment: I would like a query that can result a array of averages. Isn't possible? 

I consider that MapReduce cannot solve my problem.

Otherwise, isn't possible sum each element on same array position and return a array of sums? For example: [1,2,3] + [1,1,1] = [2,3,4]

Note: I tried average: {"$avg" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$values", 1 ] }}, but I don't want repeat this 6 times (LOL) in my query.

Comment: @JorgeRosa sorry for the delay. Can you share with me more data? Your dataset has {} but i think is []: is it? Or are your dataset in the question the real collection (maybe you just missing to write _id)?

Comment: @JorgeRosa now you have only three rows (three documents, i saw). I would to know if can happen to have 100 rows for example. I think yes because this is your Document root in your collection. Is it true?

Comment: @JorgeRosa if so, the average should be computed on 100 rows (instead of 3 like i see now). Is it?

Comment: this is my real query:

db.test_data.find({"message.testnr" : "1111"}).pretty()

and result:

`{
 "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
 "message" : {
  "testnr" : "1111",
  "content" : {
   "deflection" : [1,2,3,4,5]
  }
 }
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
 "message" : {
  "testnr" : "1111",
  "content" : {
   "deflection" : [6,7,8,9,10]
  }
 }
}
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
 "message" : {
  "testnr" : "1111",
  "content" : {
   "deflection" : [11,12,13,14,15]
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Yes can happen 100 rows or more.

Comment: For sure, i want a result of average deflection. In this case a average of element 1, 2, 3.... in one array? I'm not sure if you understand what i need

Comment: I tried and run it. If I remove `debug_documentInvolvedInTheAverage: {$push: "$$ROOT"}` list the average points sucefull. Otherwise, appear this error: `E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.",
 "code" : 16945,
 "codeName" : "Location16945"
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: Instead, appear many documents with the average position. Is possible a document with attribute "_id" with type of array with average positions?